# How to disable `Alt+Shift` key combination yet preserve `Alt+Shift+others`?

Tags: autohotkey

I can completely disable the `Alt+Shift` key combination by

```
 !Shift::return
```

However, it also disabled any additional key combinations such as `Alt+Shift+]` which I need to preserve.

So, how can I do it?

Comment: Hi @bmargulies, Would you mind telling me the additional information that is required to improve the quality of this question and hopefully to solve my problem?

Comment: your code works perfectly fine for me. I have a German keyboard, so I could not check that `]` hotkey, but I was able to disable all `ctrl+shift`-hotkeys, as those in Notepad, but keep custom hotkeys:
`^Shift::return` and `^+a::msgbox, a pressed` do not interfere

Answer (score 0):

Doing this (`!Shift::return`) will disable all OS and Program native hotkeys.

A simple way to maintain Alt+Shift+another_key shortcuts is to rewrite them in AHK like this `!+F6:: Send !+F6`.